# How can Private functions be made completely opaque?

Tags: packages

I want to make Private functions.

From my point of view, being a Private function means that the function is not accessible from other packages. For that purpose I wrote the following code. But my private function can be called in another package. I don't want that.

```
(*Package 1*)
BeginPackage["Test1`"];
Begin["`Private`"];
Test1`Private`function1[x_] := x
End[];
EndPackage[];
(*Package 2*)
BeginPackage["Test2`"]
function2[x_] := Test1`Private`function1[x]
EndPackage[]
```

As you can see from the above code, `function1` is a private function in `Test1`. That same function when called in `Test2` is still accessible, but I don't want that.

How can I resolve this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Perhaps you would care to explain why you want this behaviour?

Comment: @ruebenko for functions protection purpose.I want like that

Comment: from what do you want to protect it? It can not be done.

Comment: look at "?NDSolve`FEM`ShapeFunctionsDump`*" even in Mathematica it can not be done.

Comment: Private means one thing from your point of view, but something else from _Mathematica_'s, so the short answer to your question, "Can anyone help me?" is: no.

Comment: If you're trying to protect against accidentally calling the `Test1` private function from outside that context, then just don't use its context inside `Test2`. If, however, you're trying to hide the definition of that private function, use other techniques, e.g., `Encode`.

Comment: @ruebenko How about my suggestion?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I think you can only make it harder, but not prevent it. But +1.

Comment: Unless the package is loaded before the user has a chance to execute code, they can't. The definitions of most of the built-in functions, including `Unprotect`, `SetAttributes`, and `SetDelayed`, can be modified, and there is no guarantee that they work as advertised at the time the package is loaded. Any tricks played by the package to hide the function from the user can also be played on the package to disable the hiding functionality.

Answer (score 9):

The following should make it pretty difficult to use function1 elsewhere:

```
BeginPackage["Test1`"];
f2::usage = "f2 usage message";
Begin["`" <> StringJoin @@ RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 30] <> "`"];
function1[x_] := x;
f2[x_] := 2 function1[x];
SetAttributes[f2, {Protected, ReadProtected, Locked}];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

The trick is not to use the Private context, but a randomly named one.

f2, which uses function1, just works:

```
f2[2]
```

> 4

However, no information about function1 is leaked:

```
?function1
```

> Information::notfound: Symbol function1 not found. >>

```
?? f2
```

> f2 usage message
>
> Attributes[f2]={Locked,Protected,ReadProtected}

Saving this using `Encode` and reading it using `Get` will prevent most casual users from peeking into the function's definition.

Comment: Khm, what about [code completion](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yfoJ2.png) or just plain old ``Names["Test1`*`*"]``

Comment: The way I understood the OP's question, "The trick is not to use the Private context" in the other package is the right answer here. +1

Comment: @Ajasja Something like: `Unprotect[Names];
Names["Test1`*`*"] = "Nothing here";
Protect[Names];
SetAttributes[Names, Locked];` ? BTW Code completion stops for me at ``Test1` ``. I don't get anything more than that.

Comment: @Ajasja ?"Test1`*`*" leaks information too. I guess I'd have to overload that as well.

Comment: If the objective is to make these functions uncallable except at package load time, perhaps it's worth adding a `Condition` on `$Context` as well? Or maybe pass an additional argument that has to take a particular (secret) value in order for the function to work?

Answer (score 3):

You could make your function an inline function.

```
BeginPackage["Test1`"];
(*this is a function with several invocations, which we'd like to inline*)
function2[x_Integer] := 2 + 1
function2[x_Symbol] := x

ReleaseHold[
  Hold[
    (*Non-private definitions go here*)
    privateCaller[y_] :=
      (Print["This is some functionality."];
       function1[y]+function2[y]
      )
  ] /.
    (*inline definitions go here*)
    {
      function1[y_] :> (Print["function1 is not a defined function."]; y),
      With[{z = DownValues[function2]}, patt:function2[x_] :> Replace[patt, z]]
    }
]
Clear[function2]
EndPackage[]
```

After `EndPackage`, the symbols `function1` and `function2` have no downvalues, so unless the user can read your package definitions (which they can, if they are determined), they have no way to invoke these functions.